# How to check for numbers less than one and non-numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. For one of my assignments, I have to write JavaScript code for my class that determines and displays the tax amount on a user entered income. So far my code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript Tax Assignment</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            //declare variables and collect amount enter.
            // Assign amount entered to var amountEntered.
        var amountEntered = window.prompt("Enter an income amount in dollars");
        var x = parseInt(amountEntered);
        var untaxableIncome = 12000;
        var taxBracketOne = 36000;
        var taxBracketTwo = 90000;
        var bracketOneTax = 0.15;
        var bracketTwoTax = 0.25;
        var total;

        //determine if the number is less than one
        if (x < 1)
            {
                alert("Enter a whole number greater than 0");
            }
        //
        else if (x == NaN)
            {
                alert("Enter a whole number greater than 0");
            }

        else if (x <= untaxableIncome)
            {
                alert("You will not be charged taxes on your income");
            }

        else if (x >untaxableIncome && x <= taxBracketOne)
            {
                total = amountEntered * bracketOneTax;
                document.write("You will need to pay " + total + " on your " + amountEntered + " income.")
            }
        else if (x > taxBracketOne && x <= taxBracketTwo)
            {
                total = amountEntered * bracketTwoTax;
                document.write("You will need to pay " + total + " on your " + amountEntered + " income.")
            }
        else (x > taxBracketTwo)
            {
                document.write("I do not have the data to calculate the tax on this income.")
            }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The calculations work well, the only problem I'm having is that when I enter .5 or a letter, I do not get the alert("Enter a whole number greater than 0"); What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, how do I make the prompt box appear again if the user has entered a letter or value less than 1?

Comment: You're using ParseInt. It doesn't recognize characters or decimal values. A letter or value less than 1 (as in .5) will be zero, which is not less than zero.

Comment: I prefer to use `Math.floor(Number(x))` to truncate decimals instead of `parseInt(x)` for consistency. Also, no value in JavaScript is `==` or `===` to `NaN`, including `NaN` itself. There is a built-in function `isNaN()` for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `parseInt()`, which can only parse whole numbers, not fractions. If you type `.5`, it returns `NaN`.

But you can't test this with `if (x == NaN)`. `NaN` is a special number that's never equal to anything, not even itself. You have to use `if (isNaN(x))`.

If you want to tell if a number is a fraction between 0 and 1, you need to use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`. And if you want to tell whether the number is a whole number, you can do:

```
if (x == Math.floor(x))
```

`Math.floor()` takes a number that might have a fraction after the decimal point and returns the highest integer less than or equal to it. If the number is already an integer, these will obviously be the same.

Comment: Awesome this helped so much! One more question, how would I make the prompt box keep appearing after incorrect data is entered? I have it under the statement for IF (IS NAN(X)) { window.prompt("Enter an income amount in dollars");} However, this only makes the prompt appear once after incorrect data is entered, not every time it is entered

Comment: Use a `while()` loop and break out of it when the input meets the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use NaN as a check you need to use:

```
isNAN(x)
```

I would write it like this:

```
if( typeof x !== "number" || x > 1) {
    alert("Enter a whole number greater than 0");
}
```

MDN is a great resource for beginners:

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN](http://isNan)

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof](http://MDN%20typeof)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **isNan** function https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

So in this line

```
else if (x == NaN)
```

You have to put

```
else if (isNaN(x))
```